Obligation of sales firm to replace a customer's lost proof of purchase on request
I bought a laptop computer but lost my invoice reflecting the purchase. The computer failed after two months, and the selling firm refused to repair it under warranty as I could not produce proof of purchase. I requested a copy of the sales invoice from their own records, but they declined. Are they entitled to refuse to provide the requested copy, thus denying me the due benefit under the warranty? Do I have any legal recourse against such 'bad faith' conduct?

Why would they ask for proof of purchase from the customer if they could provide it themselves?

Do I have any legal recourse - if you take legal action, the burden of proof will be on you to prove that you have in fact purchased the item. Which will bring you back to the original problem.

@Barmar So they can deny the claim, it doesn't seem like a stretch to think that a company would still be required to have the records of a sale a few months later.

@JoeW sure they might for tax purposes, but are they required to index it among possibly thousands of others, when the conditions of sale probably state that repairs and refunds are subject to proof of purchase by the customer?

@WeatherVane I never suggested that they would have to make it easy to get, just stated what reason they would have to not provide it even if they could.

Where in the world are you? Could you just issue a GDPR request to find out what personal data they have on you (including for example invoices)?

The accepted answer here may be useful https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/can-i-compel-a-retailer-to-provide-order-details-serial-number

united-states
There is no legally enforceable obligation to provide another proof of purchase, unless there was a lawsuit over the warranty and a third-party subpoena was issued to it in that lawsuit. This isn't one of the things that as a implied part of a contract of sale. It is bad customer service, but there is no legal obligation to provide good customer service.
There is also no obligation to keep proof of purchase records for individual customers in the first place.
